# MapReduce on Amazon / Account management

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I am totally new to AWS.

I have $8700 credit from Amazon AWS. We are 87 people that I want to share this $8700 among us. (preferably $40 for each person).

1- Please guide me how I can create accounts for them and allocate like $40 to each? Or assume that they have already AWS accounts and I want to allocate $40 to each.

2- We are going to use Amazon AWS to get familiar with map-reduce. I don't know what service we should use (like EC2, Elastic ...). We prefer the easiest one. We want to use 1 computer first and run a map-reduce function on a big data-set and see how long the process takes and test it again using 4 and 8 systems to see the difference.

3- What language should we use for map reduction. Is it possible to use JAVA or C++? Where should we write our code (In netBeans, Microsoft VS, ...)? And where I can find some sample codes?

4- I am not sure about the data set either. Should it be on Oracle? Microsoft SQL SERVER ...

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

1 - you need to understand AWS Identity and Access Manager http://aws.amazon.com/iam/.  You can create users linking the same billing account.  I'm not sure if you can allot credits to individual users, but you can control access.

2 - The service you want is AWS Elastic MapReduce http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

3- What language are you most comfortable with?

> Q: What programming languages does Amazon Elastic MapReduce support?
>       You can use Java to implement Hadoop custom jars. Alternatively, you may use other languages including Perl, Python, Ruby, C++, PHP,
>   and R via Hadoop Streaming. Please refer to the Developer’s Guide for
>   instructions on using Hadoop Streaming.
>   http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#dev-8

4- I think you mean databases...I favor MySQL because its cheaper to run than MSSQL or Oracle. have you read about Amazon RDS? http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: Thanks for your great answers. 1- I've created admin group and user group and give ElasticMR access to users. Could you please help me how I can give them credit? I don't want to share the whole amount among all users and want to give each user a specific credit like $40. 4- Yes, from dataset, I mean some tables with data without considering a specific application. I really don't know how MR works. For example we need to work with a specific database application like Oracle Database, a big file or ... and I should install the database application on the service ...

Answer (score 1):

1. For amount sharing you can look at IAM role.Put yourself as Admin.
2. For Mapreduce EMR is best option as you don't have 
   to take care about complicated time sync and DNS issues.
3. Yes it is possible to use JAVA/C++.For sample code you can refer s3 bucket `s3n://elasticmapreduce/samples`  And also documentation from amazon is pretty good http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/ . You can write your code on AWS instances or you can create your local dev environment and build your code on EMR instances.
4. Is it dataset and database ?

Comment: Thanks for your great answers.
1- I've created admin group and user group and give ElasticMR access to users. Could you please help me how I can give them credit? I don't want to share the whole amount among all users and want to give each user a specific credit like $40.

4- Yes, from dataset, I mean some tables with data without considering a specific application. I really don't know how MR works. For example we need to work with a specific database application like Oracle Database, a big file or ... and I should install the database application on the service ...